# How can I connect several ds18b20 sensors to an esp32?

Tags: arduino, esp32, sensors

I want to connect 9 ds18b20 sensors to an esp32, does anyone know how the programming will be and how to get its temperature out of each one?

I don't know if the same arduino uno programming is the same for esp32

quiero conectar 9 sensores ds18b20 a un esp32, alguien sabe como sera la programacion y como sacarle la temperatura a cada uno?

no se si la misma programacion de arduino uno es igual para esp32

Answer (score 0):

it's possible

1. Connect the VCC pin of all the DS18B20 sensors to a 3.3V power
   source (e.g., ESP32's 3.3V pin).
2. Connect the GND pin of all the DS18B20 sensors to a ground pin on the ESP32.
3. Connect the DATA pin of all the DS18B20 sensors to a GPIO pin on the ESP32 which supports digital input.

here's the code:

```
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>

#define ONE_WIRE_BUS_PIN 5  // Replace with the actual GPIO pin connected to the DATA line

// Initialize the OneWire and DallasTemperature libraries
OneWire oneWire(ONE_WIRE_BUS_PIN);
DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  sensors.begin();
}

void loop() {
  sensors.requestTemperatures();

  for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    float temperature = sensors.getTempCByIndex(i);
    Serial.print("Sensor ");
    Serial.print(i);
    Serial.print(": ");
    Serial.println(temperature);
  }
  delay(1000);
}
```

Here's the example for the wiring (src : https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-multiple-ds18b20-temperature-sensors/):

> the resistor being used is 4.7K

[image: An Example of The Wiring]

The DS18B20 sensors use a unique 64-bit address to differentiate them. The code above assumes that you have connected the sensors in a sequential manner and retrieves the temperature readings by index. If your sensors have different addresses or are not connected sequentially, you will need to modify the code accordingly to read the temperature from each specific sensor using its address.